# How do you test the little things? (Eclipse Android)

Tags: java, android, eclipse

So I've been working with Eclipse for Android for about a week now. Coming from a Visual Studio background, as well as a partial Eclipse background, I've never programmed anything for the Android environment before. So I was wondering, especially if there is no one answer, how do you test the "little things". Let me explain, if I've made a class and I want to test that all the elements would work, normally in other IDEs I could simply use a "Main" to test if a class or function was working the way I want it to work. However, the only way I can think of to make a similar result would involve making a test or debug activity in the App itself and running it that way. Is there a simpler way do testing quick things?

TL:DR 
Im using Eclipse for Java Android, never have before, is there a way to test if a function or class works without having to use the Emulator or run it on an actual Android device.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_android.html

Comment: add main method in that class and run that class in debug mode.

Comment: "normally in other IDEs I could simply use a "Main" to test if a class or function was working the way I want it to work" - I'd look into unit testing if I were you, in *all* environments.

Comment: I do `System.out.println("myVariable = " + myVariable);`, for instance. By the way, how are you supposed to run your code `without having to use the Emulator or run it on an actual Android device.`?

Comment: To state the obvious: you cannot test android related function outside of an android runtime. Pure java stuff can be tested with a simple `main` if needs be.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll look into unit testing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want quick feedback that something works, there are various ways to do it.

The number one way is to build [unit tests](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidTesting/article.html). This is just writing code that test your production code. Once of the reasons this way is highly favored is because once you build a unit tests, you have that unit test forever and can execute it pretty easily and quickly. This is great for regression testing. I use Junit to build out unit tests in my own classes, that are separate from the Android framework. The Android framework provides a number of great resources to tests stuff inside that framework.

However, if you decide unit tests aren't for you, the next best way to get quick feedback would be to use the [Log](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html) class that Android provides. This just prints some statement to the logcat file of the device.

Answer (score 0):

You run your code in the simulator and/or a device, and check if everything works :)

Btw, just a friendly advice - Don't use eclipse, go straight to Android Studio.
Eclipse has waaaaaay too much bugs, and Android Studio is becoming better and better by the day.

Comment: I was recommended by a friend to do the same. I'll def check it out

Comment: Just a friendly advice too, but Android Studio is still in Beta while Eclipse's ADT is already stable. Both have each own advantages and disadvantages.

Comment: That's the point. Eclipse itself is stable, but with using Android SDK it becomes highly unstable, unlike AndroidStudio, where you experience wery few bugs, maybe. I'm just saying my several years of experience with Eclipse, before changing to Android, that works awesome for quite some time now :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a similar "main" method type of testing, you could do the same with Android development simply by putting your test code in the onCreate() method of your main (launcher) Activity. Then fire up the app in the emulator or a device.